# Is it possible to repeat a step in pyspark with python for loop

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is it possible to do something like this in pyspark to loop through each value in list and read the son files ?

The goal here is to get the app-name from directory into the table as column value and use it for partition while writing the data.

s3 location that has Json files : "s3a://abc/processing/test/raghu/date/app-name/"

```
for abc in test:

    path = "s3a://abc/processing/test/raghu/*/"+abc+"/*"

    push = sqlContext.read.json(path)

    push.registerTempTable("push")

    final = sqlContext.sql("SELECT unbase64(body.payload) as payload,"abc" as app-name from push")

    final.write.parquet("/data/test/dev/raghu/SPARK-Test/")
```

Comment: And what's the question ?

Comment: is it possible to read the son files for each app-key in S3 bucket and add the app name as a column in the table?